# How to convert PHP associative array to Java NameValuePair for HttpPost

Tags: java, php, arrays, apache

I have a piece of php code that needs to be sent via HttpPost.

```
$data = array(
'html' => '<h1 style="color:blue">Test Email</h1>
<p>Dear {name} {lname}</p>
<p>your email is {email} and phone number is {phone}</p>',
'subject' => 'email test',
'headers' => array(
'Reply-To' => 'message.replyto@example.com'
),
'from' =>   array(
'email' => 'message.reply@example.com',
'name' => 'no reply'
),
'to' => array(
 array(
'email' => 'recipient_one@example.com',
'name' => 'recipient_one',
'type' => 'to',
'vars' => array(
'name'  => 'recipient',
'lname' => 'one',
'email' => 'recipient_one@example.com',
'phone' => '8888888888',
)
);
```

So far I have tried the following neglecting any headers such as Reply-To (it is optional). The vars array above is a list of replaceable variables used in the emailer content for each user which is not very useful after converting it to NameValuePair, but have kept it because it is required according to the specification. Please neglect the number of parenthesis at the end...I have correctly used it in my code.

Edit: get a response saying "No From Address" when I append "data" to each of the pairs like below.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
            "data[html]",
            "<h1 style='color:blue'>Test Email</h1><p>Dear Example</p><p>your email is example@gmail.com and phone number is 9xxxxxxxxx</p>"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[subject]", "Test Email"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[from][email]", "example@gmail.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[from][name]", "Someone"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][email]",
            "example@gmail.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][name]", "Someone"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][type]", "to"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][vars][name]", "someone"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][vars][lname]", "someone"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][vars][email]",
            "example@gmail.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[to][0][vars][phone]", "9xxxxxxxxx"));
```

Any corrections to be made in the java code?